# select 1 -select 2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the query,
 `select id,name,feature,marks from (....)` 
I want to remove the ones whose id is present in another select statement .  
 `select id from (...)`

I'm new to sql .Is there a statement to do this directly ?

Comment: `where id not in (select id from tblTwo where ....)` or `where id IN (select id from tblTwo where ....)`

Comment: @Drew you should start posting more answers to capture more little green points.  Such points have magical properties, or so I've been told.

Comment: I got attacked by Sotirios yesterday for posting an answer to a typo question.  It was funny.  And scary.

Comment: I keep telling Sotirios to chill out in slack chat. he is going to have an aneurysm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches.

> Join:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.feature, t1.marks 
from t1
left outer join (some select statement) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

> Antijoin:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.feature, t1.marks 
from t1
where not exists (
   select id 
   from (some select statement) t2 
   where t2.id = t1.id
)
```

> "Not In":

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.feature, t1.marks 
from t1
where t1.id not in (
   select id 
   from (some select statement)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  One uses a `LEFT JOIN` to filter off the unwanted records:

```
SELECT id, name, feature, marks
FROM (...) t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The two straight forward ways are to use an `in` operator:

```
SELECT id, name, feature, marks
FORM   table1
WHERE  id NOT NOT (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

or an `exists` operator:

```
SELECT id, name, feature, marks
FORM   table1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table2
                   WHERE  table1.id = table2.id)
```